# Поиск минимальной разницы элементов двух списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Имеется два списка чисел:

```
s1 = [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
s2 = [2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 92]
```

необходимо найти разницу для каждого элемента первого списка с каждым элементом второго, после чего вывести результат в файл.

Comment: Что у вас не получается при решение данной задачи?

Comment: почему-то не мог разобраться, думал надо в цикл сочинять, как-то так:
i = 0
for element in s:
 s[3] = element1 + element2
 i = i + 1

Comment: Ну так и приводите в следующий раз то, что вы сделали. Здесь могут помочь, но с тем, чтобы сделать всё целиком за вас тут отношение довольно плохое.

Comment: благодарю за совет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [12]: s1 = [1,10,20]

In [13]: s2 = [2, 12, 22]

In [14]: min(x-y for x in s1 for y in s2)
Out[14]: -21
```

Comment: невероятно элегантное решение, спасибо

Comment: красивое решение. кстати, квадратные скобки можно убрать...

Comment: еще красивее будет если использовать вместе с `itertools.product`: `min(a-b for a,b in itertools.product(s1, s2))`

Comment: @MaxU Да, я хотел без использования модулей :) Почему-то заминусовали мой ответ :С

Comment: @Alban, не понимаю зачем минусовать правильные ответы... Поправлю карму невинно пострадавшим... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Вот:

```
l1 = [1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
l2 = [2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 92]

open(FILENAME, 'w').write(' '.join(map(lambda t: str(t[0] - t[1]), zip(l1, l2))))
```

Comment: Как быть если элементов не равное кол-во?

Comment: В задании ничего об этом не сказано, следовательно это неопределенное поведние.

Comment: спасибо, работает, правильный результат 29?

Comment: в файле вывод такой: -1 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2, но смущает вывод в iPython notebook цифры 29

Comment: скрин yadi.sk/i/0R4GOtNJ3JvJdx

Comment: все нормально. метод file.write возвращает количество записаных символов в файл. (в данном случае записано 29 символов)

Comment: Отметьте ответ галочкой, если он верен

Comment: @AndrioSkur в вопросе сказано что надо найди разницу каждого элемента 1 массива с каждым второго массива, у вас это не реализовано

Answer (score -1):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
# product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
# product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111

import itertools
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    for a, b in itertools.product(s1, s2):
        file.write('{r}={a}-{b}\n'.format(r=a-b, a=a, b=b))
```